# Editing Wordpress Plugin after uploaded

Tags: wordpress

After developing a plugin for Wordpress, I have to submit it to appear in the plugins page in Wordpress, can I edit in the plugin after uploading? 
Or do I have to upload when I absolutely done with that version? 
Thanks.

Comment: Which "plugin page"? In the WP-Admin, or the WP Plugin Repo?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to submitting your plugin to WordPress.org, then you would want that version to be completed prior to upload. Any subsequent changes would be a new version of the Plugin and should be updated accordingly. So your first release would be version 1, and a minor change might be v1.0.1 if you want to follow [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

If you are referring to changing it from within a WordPress site's admin page, then it is possible to edit the plugin file. However this is kind of a security risk.

Comment: It's possible to edit the file via WP-Admin, assuming the file permissions are set to allow it.

Comment: @rnevius I disable that functionality completely though as it gives direct access to the files to anyone who can log into the Admin Panel.

Answer (score 0):

The editing after uploading the plugin fully depends upon the file permission which you have given. Check the [WordPress Plugin Editor Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins_Editor_Screen) for editing online after upload. And also [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/plugin-editor/) link to for more details.